# search bar query not working

Tags: mysql

a search bar is with text field and a dropdown lsit.
user type the text and choose one course then submit.
i need to fetch the result of those rows which have same course chose by user.

```
my db have two tables currently  
1.content_ref_table  with fields   
title,description,content_url,course_id(fk)  

2.course_ref_table with columns  
course_id(pk),courses
```

i came up with this query,but mysql does n't support like and in operator together i guess,suggest me some query

```
select title,description,content_url from content_ref_table where title like '%eco%' and course_id  in (select course_id from course_ref_table where courses = 'b.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using join on the table:

```
select c.title,c.description,c.content_url 
from content_ref_table c inner join  course_ref_table  cf on c.course_id =cf.course_id 
where c.title like '%eco%' and cf.courses = 'b.com'
```

Comment: i also want to use c.description with like operator

Comment: @parvez:- So you can add a condition like `and c.description like '%whateveryouwanttoSearch%'`

Comment: this query is running fine,but when i'm using with stored procedure its not fetching results

Comment: @parvez:- Can you show what you are writing in stored procedure?

Comment: two parameters are search_term,courses  
select c.title,c.description,c.content_url from content_ref_table c inner join  course_ref_table  cf on c.course_id =cf.course_id 
where c.title like '%search_term%' or cf.courses = courses